# Magento 2 Swatches issue

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, swatches, magento2.1.6

I have created a configurable product with multiple options. When clicking on swatches only the first product swatch image was getting displayed but when we click on the other swatches then also the first product swatch only getting displayed.

Can any one help me on this problem? Any references or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We faced a similar type of issue in Magento 2.1.6 and upgrade the version to 2.1.7 based on some git hub article for the fix but still, the issue persists.

After doing further debugging we came to know that this issue is with catalog flat table which was enabled. When we disable the catalog flat table the configurable products swatches are started working. Please check your configuration once.

Store → Configuration → Catalog → Catalog → Use Flat Catalog Product → No

Comment: Please Update the full path of configuration.

Comment: Updated the answer, please check

Comment: It is worth to say that disabling Flat Catalog leads to some performance decrease.

Comment: On my website this setting already off but configurable images not change.